# Strange visual artifact on 'Revision' tab in Reopen Votes review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design

After switching between 'Question (revised)' and 'Revision' in the Reopen Votes review queue, the 'Revision' tab partially overlaps the boundaries of the 'Question (revised)' tab.

[image]

(latest Firefox on macOS 10.15.6 – can't reproduce in Safari, but the Revision tab does miss a boundary there)

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rRaA.gif) is a screencast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lack of border was caused by a typo, heh. Fixed!

That focus state is the expected behavior for Firefox and Chrome, just looks pretty gnarly without a border. Firefox and Chrome each apply focus states on click, though there is movement to make focus states only happen on keyboard interaction with `:focus-visible`. Once we can do that without a polyfill, we’ll likely head in that direction. Thanks for filing!